# spark sql spark.range(7).select('*,'id % 3 as "bucket").show // how to understand ('*,'id % 3 as "bucket")

Tags: apache-spark-sql

```
spark.range(7).select('*,'id % 3 as "bucket").show
// result:
+---+------+
| id|bucket|
+---+------+
|  0|     0|
|  1|     1|
|  2|     2|
|  3|     0|
|  4|     1|
|  5|     2|
|  6|     0|
+---+------+
```

```
spark.range(7).withColumn("bucket",$"id" % 3).show
///result:
+---+------+
| id|bucket|
+---+------+
|  0|     0|
|  1|     1|
|  2|     2|
|  3|     0|
|  4|     1|
|  5|     2|
|  6|     0|
+---+------+
```

I want to know what to make of *, and the whole select statement
Is the bottom of these two ways equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spark.range(7).select('*,'id % 3 as "bucket").show

spark.range(7).select($"*",$"id" % 3 as "bucket").show

spark.range(7).select(col("*"),col("id") % 3 as "bucket").show

val df = spark.range(7)

df.select(df("*"),df("id") % 3 as "bucket").show

These four ways are equivalent;
// https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column